# How to add "null" to a text file in batch?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have a problem like this. Suppose I want to write this code to a text file.

echo taskkill /IM wscript.exe /F > null

How can I do it?

Thanks to vendettamit, Matteo Italia and Roger Lipscombe :)

Comment: It's "nul", by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
   ECHO taskkill .IM wscript.exe /F ^> null > yourFile.txt
```

Answer (score 5):

[In batch the caret (`^`) is the escape character](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/05/17/599916.aspx); thus:

```
echo taskkill /IM wscript.exe /F ^>null >file.txt
```

by the way, I suppose you meant `>NUL` (`>null` will just write the data in a file named `null`).

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining.. I was coding a batch app for pentesting ... Thanks again :)